# Incorrect pointer created within a function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to implement an integer vector in C. The vector pointer created in `vector_copy` is aroung 0x3 or 0x2, which causes segmentation fault. Why is that happenning?
This really baffles me since I have a similar implementation for `vector_new`.

```
typedef struct vector {
    int* items;
    size_t size;
    size_t max;
} vector;
```

```
vector* vector_copy(vector* v) {
    vector* v2;

    memcpy(v2->items,v->items,v->max * sizeof(int*));
    if (v2->items == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    v2->size = v->size;
    v2->max = v->max;
    return v2;
}
```

```
vector* vector_new(size_t initial_capacity) {
    vector* newv;
    newv->items = malloc(initial_capacity * sizeof(int*));
    if (newv->items == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    newv->size = 0;
    newv->max = initial_capacity;
    return newv;
}
```

```
int main() {
    vector* v;
    vector* v2;

    v = vector_new(4);
    //new vector with capacity 4 and size 0

    vector_push(v, 1);
    vector_push(v, 2);
    //1 and 2 are pushed back

    v2=vector_copy(v);
    //vector is supposed to be copied

    vector_free(v);
    vector_free(v2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `vector_copy` looks pretty broken.  `v2` is undefined, but you immediately try to do a `memcpy` into it.  You need to allocate memory for it first, e.g. via `malloc`.

Comment: `vector* newv;    newv->items` you dereference an uninitialized pointer

Answer (score 1):

```
vector* v2;
memcpy(v2->items,v->items,v->max * sizeof(int*));
```

This is *not* a good idea. You have basically created a pointer `v2` that points to some *arbitrary* location (because you haven't initialised it), with the `v2` pointer value probably being whatever was left over on the stack from some previous operation<sup>(a)</sup>. Then, by copying bytes to that arbitrary location, all sorts of weirdness may ensue.

You need to actually *allocate* some memory for this new vector, with something like:

```
vector *v2 = vector_new(v->max);
memcpy(v2->items, v->items, v->max * sizeof(int));
```

You'll (hopefully) also notice I've changed the `sizeof` to use `int` rather than `int*`. I suspect that `items` points to an array of the former in which case that's the correct value to use.

---

So the following function is a better starting point:

```
vector *vector_copy(vector* v) {
    // Use vector_new to get empty one with exact same properties.

    vector *v2 = vector_new(v->max);
    if (v2 == NULL) return NULL;

    // Copy data in to it and return.

    memcpy(v2->items, v->items, v->max * sizeof(int));
    v2->size = v->size;

    return v2;
}
```

---

You also have the exact same issues (no structure allocation and wrong `sizeof`) in your `new` function, which can be fixed with:

```
vector *vector_new(size_t initial_capacity) {
    // Allocate a vector structure, fail if no go.

    vector *newv = malloc(sizeof(vector));
    if (newv == NULL) return NULL;

    // Allocate the data area, free structure and fail if no go.

    newv->items = malloc(initial_capacity * sizeof(int));
    if (newv->items == NULL) {
        free(newv);
        return NULL;
    }

    // Set up everything needed and return it.

    newv->size = 0;
    newv->max = initial_capacity;

    return newv;
}
```

The fact that this function sets the maximum based on `initial_capacity` relieves you of the necessity of setting `max` in `vector_copy()`.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> I state "probably" because of the way many implementations work in terms of reusing stack frame memory regions. However, it's by no means guaranteed, just one possibility. You should just assume that it will have some random value and will therefore behave appropriately (or inappropriately, depending on your viewpoint).

Comment: @Eric, there's a subtle distinction between "pointing to probably something" and "probably pointing to something". The former is a definite statement, the latter (what I meant) a likely situation based on the way most implementations work. If you call a function then return, then call another function, the stack frame will often be in the same memory area so uninitialised locals will probably get values from the first call. It's not guaranteed (hence my "probably" comment) but it is likely. You're correct in that it's no way mandated so I'll try make that clearer ...

Comment: @Eric: Ah, never mind, I think I see what you're getting at. My original language, now changed, could be easily read as `v2` *pointing* to some point on the stack. I've clarified it to now state that the `v2` pointer itself (not what it points to) is the probable stack-leftover info. Hopefully that's clearer. If not, I'm open to any suggestions you may have on improving.